# impossible segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm running the following code:

```
if (tuple != NULL) {

    printf("tuple is not null\n\n"); fflush(stdout);
    if (tuple->tuple != NULL) {
        printf("tuple tuple is not null\n\n"); fflush(stdout);
        int i;
        for (i = tuple->tuple_dimension -1; i >= 0 ; i--)
            if (tuple->tuple[i] != NULL) {
                free(tuple->tuple[i]);
            }
            else
                break;
        free(tuple->tuple);
    }
    printf("i got here :D\n\n"); fflush(stdout);
    free(tuple);
}
```

It runs perfectly on the first go but the second time it seems to fail on the condition of the second `if` and gives me a segmentation fault. I receive this output:

```
tuple is not null
tuple tuple is not null
i got here :D
tuple is not null
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

From my understanding it neither entered the `if` body nor did it skip it, so it failed upon calling `tuple -> tuple`, but how can this be possible if we know that `tuple` is not null?

Comment: Null is not the only way a pointer can be invalid...

Comment: `tuple = NULL;` after that entire fiasco will likely help considerably the next time you use that var on your "next go-around". Assuming, of course, you bother checking it in the secret code that builds this thing.

Comment: Print the pointers with the `%p` format (and a cast to `(void *)` in the argument list).  Look at the numerology.  You may have an a number that isn't 0 in the range 1..1023; that'll normally crash too (on a desktop or server system). Sometimes, the first 4 KiB is unmapped.  Or it could be a much larger but still bogus address.  Also, printing to standard error is unbuffered or line buffered; you don't have to keep using `fflush()` if you write to it.

Comment: Probably the second time around, `tuple` is not null but is not pointing to a valid object. (For example, pointing to memory that has been freed). To get better help post more code.